# What is the pythonic way of setting fields of a dict in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

I have two lists, one containing int values:

```
values = [5,10,15,20]
```

the other is a list of dicts:

```
dicts = [{'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0},
         {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0},
         {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0},
         {'a':0, 'b': 0, 'c':0}]
```

I want to get the first value from values list and set the field "a" of the first dict with the value coming from the "values" list and so on. In other words output should be:

```
dicts = [{'a':5, 'b':0, 'c':0},
         {'a':10, 'b':0, 'c':0},
         {'a':15, 'b':0, 'c':0},
         {'a':20, 'b': 0, 'c':0}]
```

What is the Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: what about the `b` and `c` keys? are their values going to remain 0?

Comment: Your syntax for dictionaries was  wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you could use a `zip` to set the value for `'a'` for every dictionary. Something like:

```
for dic,val in zip(dicts,values):
    dic['a'] = val
```

Or putting it in a *one-liner*:

```
for dic,val in zip(dicts,values): dic['a'] = val
```

Note that there is *no difference* with the previous code fragment. It depends on what your eye likes the most.

We here **update** the dictionaries: we do no create copies, etc. That is an important distinction since variables that could reference to the given dictionaries will reflect the changes we make.

`zip(..)` takes as input a sequence or more iterables (here `dicts` and `values`) and generates tuples of elements of these iterables. So it emits:

```
(values[0],dicts[0]), (values[1],dicts[1]), ...
```

Now we do *tuple-unpacking*: we unify `val` and `dic` with one of the `values` and one of the `dicts`. For each of the tuples we thus set the `dic['a']` value.

Console test:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> values = [5,10,15,20]
>>> dicts = [{'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0},
...          {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0},
...          {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0},
...          {'a':0, 'b': 0, 'c':0}]
>>> for dic,val in zip(dicts,values): dic['a'] = val
... 
>>> dicts
[{'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'a': 5}, {'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'a': 10}, {'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'a': 15}, {'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'a': 20}]
```

Comment: Really, don't put it on one line under the misguided belief that it carries some sort of benefit. It does not.

Comment: @chepner: well for the Python parser there is no difference at all as far as I know. But it is more compact.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. This is indeed what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of a Pythonic one-liner (although I **strongly suggest you prefer Willem's answer for clarity/readability**):

```
dicts = [{key: val if key != 'a' else z_val 
            for key, val in d.items()} for d, z_val in zip(dicts, values)]

dicts
Out[5]: 
[{'a': 5, 'b': 0, 'c': 0},
 {'a': 10, 'b': 0, 'c': 0},
 {'a': 15, 'b': 0, 'c': 0},
 {'a': 20, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}]
```

Edit: Removed the redundant `if` `else` for the dictionary keys.

Comment: Mind that this will make a **copy** of the dictionary. This can be an important difference since other variables referencing to the *old* dictionaries will not reflect on the changes. (I'm not saying this is a problem, but it is perhaps worth noting that).

Comment: @StefanPochmann I was just looking at that... A bit redundant, yeah? Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
values = [5,10,15,20]
dicts = [{'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0},
         {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0},
         {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0},
         {'a':0, 'b': 0, 'c':0}]

res1 =  dict(zip(dicts[0],zip(*[d.values() for d in dicts])))# tronspose a list of dicts /// res1 = {'a': (0, 0, 0, 0), 'c': (0, 0, 0, 0), 'b': (0, 0, 0, 0)}
res1['a'] = values
res = [dict(zip(res1,t)) for t in zip(*res1.values())]# tronspose res1
```